# ¿Por qué al utilizar la condicional "If" en Python, la salida es diferente?

Tags: python, python-3.x

estoy aprendiendo python y estuve intentando hacer un formulario que guarde la información que escribe un usuario en la terminal, en un archivo de texto.

En esta parte del código se supone que "debería" escribir en el archivo de texto (En el caso de que "my_ag" fuese menor que 18) "Is a student: (Respuesta del Usuario)".

El problema es que sin importar si escribo "Yes" o "No", el resultado siempre es "Is a Student: Yes" y no entiendo por qué.

Aquí está el pedazo de código que no me funciona

He estado buscando tanto aquí como en Google y no he encontrado ninguna solución, ¿alguien me podría ayudar?

```py
my_ag = int(input(">>>I'm "))

stud = "So you are an student?"
work = "So did you went to the university?"

if(my_ag < 18):
    print(stud)
    yesno = input(">>>")
else:
    print(work)
    yesno = input(">>>")

if(my_ag < 18 and yesno == "yes" or "Yes"):
    swo = "Yes"
elif(my_ag < 18 and yesno == "no" or "No"):
    swo = "No"

file = open("MyInfo.txt", 'w')
file.write("\nIs a Student: ")
file.write(swo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Un string es verdadero en una expresión lógica. Esta `if` imprime `True`.

```
if "Yes":
    print(True)
```

Usa entonces

```
yesno = yesno.lower()
if my_ag < 18:
    swo = "Yes" if yesno == "yes" else "No"
```

Siempre conviene convertir a minúsculas (o mayúsculas) antes de examinar la opción. Asi cubres todos los casos posibles: Yes, yes, yES, yES.